# Only 1 Facebook friends is shown - using FB Javascript SDK jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to show a list of all Facebook friends of the logged in user. However, using the code as shown below only 1 Facebook friend is shown - instead of all. Anybody any idea what might the issue? I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK together with jQuery.

Thanks!
Ron

```
      FB.api( {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM      friend WHERE uid2 = ' + FB.getSession().uid +')'
      },
      function(response) { 
        for(i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
            $('#friend-info').html('<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + response[0].uid + '/picture"><br />').fadeIn('fast');
            }
        } 
      );
```

Comment: You just need more Facebook friends :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like you mean to do this:

`response[i]` instead of `response[0]`

`i` is the incrementing variable but you're using `0` as the index each time.

And as [Jimmy Sawczuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984915/only-1-facebook-friends-is-shown-using-fb-javascript-sdk-jquery/5984960#5984960) mentioned, use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) (which overwrites the existing html):

Full code with those fixes:

```
  FB.api( {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM      friend WHERE uid2 = ' + FB.getSession().uid +')'
  },
  function(response) { 
    for(i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
        $('#friend-info').append('<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + response[i].uid + '/picture"><br />').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    } 
  );
```

However, it looks like [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984915/only-1-facebook-friends-is-shown-using-fb-javascript-sdk-jquery/5984993#5984993) probably has a solution for you that could make more sense overall.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! Kind off new to jQuery - as you probably already noticed :-)

Answer (score 3):

`$.html` overwrites whatever html is in the container, so in addition to what Wesley Murch recommends, you should change your `.html` to `.append`.

Comment: Good catch, I just came back to make sure his `i` starts at 0 and not 1 :)

Comment: :) Feel free to lift what I have and make your answer complete for posterity.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just after a list of friends, why not use the Graph API instead of a query

```
FB.api('/me/friends?fields=uid,name,picture', function(response) {
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var friend = response[i];
        // etc
    }
});
```

Comment: Hehe, 3 separate answers that would probably work well as one. Happy for Wesley to take my answer too

Comment: I would think of this as a separate solution. I have no idea about the Facebook aspect of this, only the javascript part. The other two answers fix the code and yours provides a possibly better alternative. The title is what dragged me in here `Only 1 Facebook friends is shown`... I was like "Awwwww.. so sad!" :)

Comment: Thanks guys for your feedback! Phil, I tried your solution, but somehow I couldn't it get it to work... Will try it again tomorrow morning - I think it's a neat solution.